# Hyper-V Manager - Use HTTPS with WinRM

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, winrm

I've successfully configured WinRM on my Hyper-V server to use HTTPS. I am able to connect to it and execute commands from my client PC by using the same local username and password on both (they are in a Workgroup) e.g. `winrs -r:https://<server>:5986 dir`.

However I can't figure out what address to specify in the "Connect to Server" dialog box in Hyper-V Manager to make it use HTTPS. By default it only tries to connect via HTTP which fails, since I do not want to add an insecure TrustedHosts exception. The error message itself states that I can use HTTPS instead of TrustedHosts.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding other people with this issue. By reading [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-admin-center/securing-ssl-winrm-connection-to-remote-servers/m-p/142022) topic, I'm getting the impression that any client application that utilizes WinRM has to explicitly implement SSL/HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Enable-PSRemoting
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "fqdn-of-hyper-v-host"
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer "fqdn-of-hyper-v-host"

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Credentials Delegation > Allow delegating fresh credentials with NTLM-only server authentication
Click Enable and add wsman/fqdn-of-hyper-v-host.

Comment: Isn't this still using the `TrustedHosts` method with goes over cleartext rather than SSL?